# Determine if variable has ANY text

Tags: php, variables, string-comparison

I would like to determine whether or not a variable has any text at all.
For instance, my current code is this:

```
if (is_numeric ($id)) 
{
  //do stuff
} 
else 
{
  // do other stuff 
}
```

However, there is a problem if my variable contains both a string and a number
such as "you are 93 years old",
because it sees that number 93 is present and considers the variable numeric.
I want the if statement to only "do stuff" if there is absolutely no text in the variable at all.

Thanks

Comment: How can the function return true for that string? Have you tried running the code for that value, are you checking the right variable, etc? You may need to run more tests.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. I'm sure it is the right variable. Also, what do you mean how can it return true?

Comment: The reason he asks "how can it return true" is that the function `is_numeric()` will return true iff the entire string contains numbers or decimals... Ie: your example of `is_numeric('you are 93 years old')` will always return `false`.

Even a comma (,) will cause `is_numeric` to return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the value to int (or float) then compare it back to the unaltered version. They should match values (but not type)

```
if((int)$id == $id) {
} else {
}
```

another option would be to use `preg_match("/^([\d.\-]+)$/", $id)`. This would allow you to be very specific about what characters you let $id contain. However using regexp should be considered as the final choice (for performance reasons)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($var) && $var !== "0" && $var !== 0) {
    // it's really empty, not a string "0" and not a numeric 0
}
```

You could also check if it's not a boolean `false` for the sake of completeness.